# How to avoid the screen turning on for each notification?

Tags: notifications, settings, screen, nokia-3

#### Problem

I have a Nokia 3 with stock Android installed, not rooted. Whenever the phone receives a notification, the screen turns on. I wish to change this, mostly because it drains the battery and causes me to activate the camera in my pocket.

In fact, I would appreciate if the screen **only** turns on when I press the power button.

**Edit** As was said in the comments, the Nokia comes with Android 7 (Nougat) installed.

#### What I have tried so far

- Just for the record, I did browse through the settings of the phone looking for an obvious choice, and could not find any way to turn it off.
- I have tried every possible setting for lockscreen notifications to no avail.
- There is no [Ambient display](https://www.howtogeek.com/255696/how-to-disable-androids-ambient-display/) option in the Display section of my settings.
- There is a screensaver option there, but whether it is on or off makes no difference.
- After reading [this](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/602793-turn-screen-wake-off-notifications.html), I tried using another text message application than the default. That also did not help.

Comment: Which Android Version

Comment: @beeshyams Android 7+. Nokia 3 is shipped with Nougat out-of-the-box and we don't have Android O as of now, right?

Comment: Try [Macrodroid Automation app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). Trigger : Notification received> any application > any text ; Action: Screen off; constraints : leave blank

Comment: @beeshyams [You should totally drop that and try Macrodroid Automation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/350567) Lol.

Comment: @iBug: oh got it,  but I won't  drop it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Googled around and am afraid this is the default setting for Android 7. People from all over the Internet are complaining about this. You can't simply turn it off.

However I found [this trick](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/stop-notifications-waking-your-screen-when-do-not-disturb-is-enabled-in-android-7/) working by entering Do Not Disturb mode. In Settings -> (Modes) -> DND there's a switch named **Block visual disturbances**. Turning it on and putting your phone into DND mode should work. As a side-effect, some other things are also changed in DND mode.

Comment: Frustrating, but I was soberly expecting this. I had hoped I had missed something. I will try both the DnD approach and also the macdroid autmation suggestion of yours from the comments and see what makes me least unhappy.

Comment: This sounds like the **Ambient Display** feature. Are you certain that it cannot be disabled?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman It can be disabled when compiling the ROM, which is OT here. As far as I've found on Google there isn't a user option to disable it. Custom ROMs may provide one but that highly depends.

Comment: @iBug That's the catch. While LineageOS 14.1 allows to disable the setting, I was unsure about other Nougat flavors.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman OnePlus 5 with stock OOS. No option available.

Comment: As a comment, this is definitely Ambient Display feature. The DND solution stops the screen from turning on when a notification is received, but the screen still turns on sometimes for no apparent reason, which is consistent with what Ambient apprently does (sometimes). This is very annoying.